# symfony2 access control restrict ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

Tags: php, symfony, access-control, symfony-security

I want to restrict some routes from being accessed by all roles (SUPER_ADMIN, ADMIN included) except for (ROLE_CUSTOM)

Where ROLE_CUSTOM is a custom role created for specified route.

The only role can access this route is (ROLE_CUSTOM)

I want to control this from security.access_control.yml or from firewall configuration.

I know i can use is_granted function but i want to control it from security.access_control.yml or from firewall configuration.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roles are simple, and are basically strings that you invent and use as needed, so `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` and `ROLE_ADMIN` are already custom roles created by you. **Then everything depends on your role hierarchy** ([Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles)):

```
security:   
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CUSTOM:      ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

To allow you to protect URL patterns for users with `ROLE_CUSTOM` just do the following ([Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-url-patterns-access-control)):

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/exclusive-path$, role: ROLE_CUSTOM }
```

Ready! only users with `ROLE_CUSTOM` can access to `/exclusive-path` paths.